# Can k-means clustering error ever increase?

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have implemented k-means clustering algorithm for 20-dimensional histograms.  It seems to be working well on 2-dimensional histograms.

Occassionally, the sum of squared errors will increase slightly after an iteration.  Is this normal, or a sign of an underlying bug?

If it is possible to increase the SSE, can anyone provide an example that I can visualise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The assignment *must not* increase.

Seems as if you have a bug somewhere. Maybe you are using something other than squared Euclidean distance?

SSE = sum of squared errors, not sum of distances or something else based on distances.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I expected that to be the case, but I thought I should check before I went wading through.

I've been calculating SSE as the sum of the squares of the distances from the centroid to each point in the cluster, and the overall SSE as the sum of each of these.  Is this wrong?  If so, what should I be measuring?

Comment: Measure the sum of squared differences in each dimension. Don't think in distances, this is misleading. k-means minimizes *sums of variances*. `SSE = sum_x min_c sum_d (x_d - c_d)^2` where `x` are data points, `c` are cluster centers, and `d` are dimensions.

Comment: That's what I meant by distance.  I'll use the correct term in future.   I'll have to figure out why the SSE is increasing - clearly I've got a bug somewhere. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: A lot of people add in a `sqrt` somewhere, as in Euclidean distance, or an extra square term... If I am not mistaken, the sum of Euclidean distances does *not* always decrease in k-means: Assuming I have two objects with distances 2 and 2. Reassigning these so that the distances become 4 and 1 increases the absolute sum of distances (from 4 to 5), but reduces the sum of squares (17 to 8). So optimizing Euclidean distance is not the same as optimizing variances.